# All item vs All items

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am a little bit confused about **All Items** or **All Item**. Which one is correct and why? I will use this on the website application as a menu item. In my point of view, while I use **All** before the **Item**, that's mean it's plural, NOT singular. So, can I use ALL ITEM instead of ALL ITEMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"All item" means that you have one item and all its' elements as the whole thing, whereas "all items" means that you have a lot of items and you mention not only one of them, but all amount of them.
I'd rather use "all items", thus it means "all products".